# Presenting a view controller in tvOS

Tags: objective-c, tvos

I am trying to present a view controller in a `tvOS` application, but neither of the included code snippets present one. What am I missing?

Code 1 :

```
 DinoViewController *dinoVC = [[DinoViewController alloc]init];
        dinoVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:dinoVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Code 2 :

```
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        DinoViewController *dinoVC = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        dinoVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:dinoVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Are you sure your `dinoVC` isn't deallocated directly after? Maybe you need to keep a reference to it somewhere.

Comment: can you provide more context ?

Comment: @robo This is all of it ! just a simple presentation it's not a weird  thing !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the correct answer: Mention `Identifier` in the tvOS storyboard, (not the same in iOS,) and then implement this code:

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *dinoVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Page1"];
    [self presentViewController:dinoVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this..

```
 DinoViewController *dinoVC = [[DinoViewController alloc]init];
        dinoVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

   [self showViewController:dinoVC sender:nil];
```

hope this will hope u

Comment: The result is the same ! it shows nothing  on the scene